# Работа php скрипта в промежутке даты

Tags: php

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать , чтобы скрипт отрабатывал в промежуток даты
15.12.текущего года и 15.01.следующего 
Тоесть в новогодние праздники

```
<?php 

    $today = date("j.n.Y");
    $yers = date("Y");
    $datestart = date("15.12.Y"); 
    if(date("m")  == 12){
        $nextYers = $yers + 1;
    }else{
        $nextYers = $yers;
    }
    $dateend = "10.01.". $nextYers; 
    if((strtotime($today) > strtotime($datestart)) &&(strtotime($today) < strtotime($dateend))){?>
       //Тут нужный код
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: На крон поставь и всё, зачем мучиться с кодом...

Answer (score 2):

Зачем такие сложности?
Во-первых, предположим, что скрипт стоит в кроне на каждый день в определённое время. Ведь именно крон запускает скрипт. (Ну или вручную каждый день) Если, конечно не предполагается бесконечное выполнение скрипта.
Вы можете сравнивать дату как строки взяв от текущей даты только день и месяц. 
К примеру:

```
$today = date("d.m");
$startDate = "15.12";
$endDate = "10.01";

if ($today <= $endDate or $today >= $startDate){
    echo 'Выполнение скрипта';
}
```